# ProxmoxVE unable to login from Server native CLI

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line-interface, proxmox

Something Odd just started happening with one of our development server Nodes. Suddenly I'm not able to login as "root" from the ProxmoxVE (5.0-30) from the native CLI. The funny thing is that we can still remotely ssh with the same root user credentials. But never from the servers CLI anymore.

Did anyone faced similar issues ???

Answer (score 0):

From my side I'm not experiencing your described issue.
I'm running a (remotely administered) Server of Proxmox VE on Version 5.1-38 (so newer than yours). Did some updates, including kernel just yesterday. Not sure if you're using the Enterprise repo for the dev server (I'm doing).

Note: I assume you mean the Web GUI?

Now...

- Are you sure you're connecting over HTTPS?
- Have you tried running `netstat -apn | grep 8006`? You should see that "pveproxy" is running on that port.
- You can check `/var/log/pveproxy/access.log` for entries if you're trying to connect.
- If it's not working, you could also try cleaning or reinstalling pve-manager.

`apt-get remove pve-manager
apt-get update 
apt-get install pve-manager`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already tried pve-manager update etc. And it's not the GUI that I'm talking about, rather the back-end shell. Remote login via ssh works fine. But from iDRAC console, it doesn't. Very strange. :(

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Dell-based server. Mine is based on a Supermicro board and their IPMI solution works fine as far as I can tell. I only found one thread for now - https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/unable-to-connect-to-proxmox-but-still-able-to-connect-to-containers.38522/